# Open multiple files from a file

Tags: python

I need to open a file that have multiple absolute file directories.

EX:

Layer 1 = *C:\User\Files\Menu\Menu.snt*

Layer 2 = *C:\User\Files\N0 - Vertical.snt*

The problem is that when I try to open *C:\User\Files\Menu\Menu.snt* python doesn't like *\U* or *\N*

I could open using `r"C:\User\Files\Menu\Menu.snt"` but I can't automate this process.

```
file = open(config.txt, "r").read()
list = []

for line in file.split("\n"):
    list.append(open(line.split("=",1)[1]).read())
```

It prints out:

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 33-34: malformed \N character escape
```

Comment: does `list.append(open(r"{}".format(line.split("=",1)[1])).read())` work?

Comment: `SyntaxError` happens at **compile** time, not at runtime. The error does not match your code.

Answer (score 2):

The backslash character `\` is used as an escape character by the Python interpreter in order to provide special characters.

For example, `\n` is a "New Line" character, like you would get from pressing the Return key on your keyboard.

So if you are trying to read something like `newFolder1\newFolder2`, the interpreter reads it as:

```
newFolder1
ewFolder2
```

where the New Line character has been inserted between the two lines of text.

You already mentioned one workaround: using raw strings like `r'my\folder\structure'` and I'm a little curious why this can't be automated.

If you can automate it, you could try replacing all instances of a single backslash (`\`) with a double backslash (`\\`) in your file paths and that should work.

Alternatively, you can try looking in the `os` module and dynamically building your paths using `os.path.join()`, along with the `os.sep` operator.

One final point: You can save yourself some effort by replacing:

`list.append(open(line.split("=",1)[1]).read())`

by

`list = open(line.split("=",1)[1]).readlines()`

Comment: Your code replacement suggestion will result in only the last file's lines being contained in the list.

Comment: Also, "the interpreter reads it as" is not entirely true, depending on where the data comes from.

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution:

```
file = open("config.txt", "r").readlines()
list = [open(x.split("=")[1].strip(), 'r').read() for x in file]
```

readlines creates a list that contains all lines in file, there is no need to split the whole string.